# BigQuery/SQL: dataset transformation using SELF JOIN and LAG

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, data-manipulation

I have an input dataset similar to the following dummy dataset:

```
date      time      userid  channel    transaction
20161012  12:00:00  1       seo        0
20161018  16:50:00  1       referral   1
20161011  09:20:00  2       sea        0
20161020  12:20:00  2       direct     0
20161020  20:40:00  2       facebook   0
20161021  11:35:00  2       direct     1
20161019  01:05:00  3       seo        0
20161020  24:20:00  3       sea        1
20161021  06:20:00  4       direct     1
```

I would like to get the following output dataset:

```
userid channel1  channel2
1      seo       referral
1      referral  transaction
2      sea       direct
2      direct    facebook
2      facebook  direct
2      direct    transaction
3      seo       sea
3      sea       transaction
4      direct    transaction
```

In words, I want to create a dataset which records all steps between channels that follow each other in the customer journey. Denote that in the output datset transaction is regarded as a channel.

I know that I might be able to achieve something like this by using `JOIN` (on itself) and `LAG` but I am not able to make it work...

Anyone that knows a simple solution to obtain this output dataset?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @MikhailBerlyant for your feedback. Though, I haven't used your answer for my final solution. That is why I haven't accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery Legacy SQL does support [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) including [LAG()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#lag) and [LEAD()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#lead)

Same true for BigQuery Standard SQL - see [Analytic Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#analytic-functions), as well as [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql)

Try below in BigQuery dialect of your choice

```
SELECT 
  userid, channel1, IFNULL(channel2, "transaction") AS channel2, transaction
FROM (
  SELECT 
    userid, DATE, TIME, transaction, channel AS channel1, 
    LEAD(channel) OVER(PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY DATE, TIME) AS channel2
  FROM YourTable
// ORDER BY userid, DATE, TIME
```